# Why can Python's Event.wait() be interrupted by signals on some systems but not others?

Tags: python, signals

Consider the following Python script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Event

event = Event()
start = datetime.now()

try:
    event.wait(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught Ctrl+C after %s" % (datetime.now() - start))
```

When I run it on Debian (specifically, Docker's python:3.6.5-stretch) and quickly press Ctrl+C, it gets interrupted immediately:

```
# python mptest.py
^Ccaught Ctrl+C after 0:00:00.684854
#
```

But when I run it on Alpine (specifically, Docker's python:3.6.5-alpine3.7) and quickly press Ctrl+C, it lets the entire wait finish:

```
/ # python mptest.py 
^Ccaught Ctrl+C after 0:00:05.000314
/ #
```

What's the reason for this difference? Is one of the systems incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short version:**

Python assumes that `sem_timedwait` will return with `EINTR` if a signal interrupts it while it's waiting. Glibc (Debian's libc) does this, but POSIX says doing it is optional, and musl (Alpine's libc), doesn't do it.

**Long version:**

Python's `Event` is [built around `Condition`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/threading.py#L498-L500) internally, which is itself [built around `Lock`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/threading.py#L215-L237). The following program exhibits the same behavior for the same reason with just `Lock`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Lock

lock = Lock()
lock.acquire()
start = datetime.now()

try:
    lock.acquire(True, 5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught Ctrl+C after %s" % (datetime.now() - start))
```

From [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire):

> Lock acquires can now be interrupted by signals on POSIX.

Assuming that this bit of documentation is correct, it means that the behavior on Debian is correct and the behavior on Alpine is incorrect.

Python's `acquire` is [built around `sem_timedwait`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/thread_pthread.h#L350) (assuming it's present, which it is on both Debian and Alpine. If it weren't present, it would instead be [built around `pthread_cond_timedwait`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/thread_pthread.h#L499)).

The following C program demonstrates the inconsistency of `sem_timedwait` when built on each of the systems:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int sig) {
   puts("in signal handler");
}

int main() {
   struct sigaction sa;
   sa.sa_handler = handler;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   sa.sa_flags = 0;
   sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

   alarm(1);

   struct timespec ts;
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
   ts.tv_sec += 2;

   sem_t sem;
   sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
   sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts);

   if(errno == EINTR) {
      puts("Got interrupted by signal");
   } else if(errno == ETIMEDOUT) {
      puts("Timed out");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

On Debian, it exits after 1 second with "Got interrupted by signal". On Alpine, it exits after 2 seconds with "Timed out".

`sem_timedwait` is a libc function [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_timedwait.html#tag_16_508_05). In particular, it states that it "may" fail with EINTR, not that it "shall". This means that neither glibc (Debian's) nor musl (Alpine's) is incorrect.

For [historical reasons due to bugs in old kernels](http://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2018/02/24/3), musl [made the conscious decision to not support EINTR where they don't have to](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=c0ed5a201b2bdb6d1896064bec0020c9973db0a1).

In my opinion, fault here lies with Python for relying on an optional feature of POSIX. As it turns out, Python has been bitten by [a similar issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue11223) before, in the case where it uses `pthread_cond_timedwait` due to semaphores not being present. Also, this issue causes [one of Python's self-tests](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/test/test_threadsignals.py#L75-L99) to fail when built against musl. I opened [Python bug #34004](https://bugs.python.org/issue34004) regarding this.